# Python csv to json column order

Tags: python, json, csv

Basic Python csv to json script gets the column order mixed up in the final JSON.  Any idea why?

**test.csv**

```
animal,age,count,legs
dogs,3,5,4
cats,6,4,4
birds,2,1,2
```

**script**

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('test.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('test.json', 'w')

reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile)

jsonfile.write('[')
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write(',\n')
jsonfile.write(']')
```

**test.json**

```
[{"count": "5", "age": "3", "legs": "4", "animal": "dogs"},
{"count": "4", "age": "6", "legs": "4", "animal": "cats"},
{"count": "1", "age": "2", "legs": "2", "animal": "birds"},
]
```

Comment: You can use this to get ordered dictionary http://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

Comment: json is not ordered. nor is  a python dict.

Comment: @njzk2 it does as far as `Object.keys(json[0])` is concerned

Comment: @geotheory it is merely a coincidence. don't rely on that. (you'll also notice that small integers are sorted in a `set`, but that does not mean that other keys will be)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because dictionary does not have any sense of order, so it is expected that the dictionaries are in arbitrary order.

If you must preserve the order (and ideally you should not have to), you would need to read each row using a simple csv reader, and then create [`collection.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) objects, that do store the order in which keys are added. Example -

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
with open('test.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headerlist = next(reader)
    csvlist = []
    for row in reader:
            d = OrderedDict()
            for i, x in enumerate(row):
                    d[headerlist[i]] = x
            csvlist.append(d)

import json
with open('test.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(csvlist,f)
```

Please note this would still be useless if the parser who would be using this JSON does not respect the order in the same way.

---

Example/Demo -

With my `test.csv` as -

```
animal,age,count,legs
dogs,3,5,4
cats,6,4,4
birds,2,1,2
```

`test.json` looked like -

```
[{"animal": "dogs", "age": "3", "count": "5", "legs": "4"}, 
{"animal": "cats", "age": "6", "count": "4", "legs": "4"}, 
{"animal": "birds", "age": "2", "count": "1", "legs": "2"}]
```

Comment: But why is this giving rows in the same order every time

Comment: @VigneshKalai, The order of a dict isn't random, it just doesn't match the order they are expecting.

Comment: @JasonSperske that makes sense but then there is some kind of ordering in dictonary

Comment: VigneshKalai, Because row remember it's items but dictionary does not because it depend upon the key value structure.

Comment: @JasonSperske The issue occurs in `reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile)`  and then reading each row from it ,don't think there is any hook to have ordered dict there.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, good point, looks like the OP will need to read column by column into an OrderedDict

Comment: @VigneshKalai, the order comes from the hash of the keys (which is the same every time)

Comment: Rows are entires in a list, which preserves order.

Comment: This is nuts.  I literally can't find a csv2json script that works properly.  Half of them produce lists (not arrays) of json documents, and the other half require you to name headers explicitly.  Guess I'm going to have to write it myself.

Comment: You can check the code I gave, it should work for all csvs (that have headers) .

Comment: this is useless. even if the json file presents the data in some order, there is no guaranty that the parser will respect it.

Comment: Well it works for me, at least for now. Thanks Anand

Comment: why are numbers returned as strings?

Answer (score 4):

In Anand's answer you are only temporarily solving the problem. The JSON file may be output in the correct order, but then you could have this data read in another location (such as the browser or another Python process), and when it reads in this file, the order will not be preserved!

You will want to use a **list of lists** if you want to guarantee order between your data source and its destination.

You can do the following to preserve order:

```
import csv 
import json

lst = []
csvfile = open('test.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('test.json', 'w')
first_line = next(csvfile).split(',')

csvfile.seek(0) # we peeked at the first_line, lets reset back to beginning

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

for row in reader:
    group = []
    for h in first_line:
        h = h.strip()
        group.append([h, row[h]])
    lst.append(group)

jsonfile.write(json.dumps(lst))
```

Output:

```
[[["animal", "dogs"], ["age", "3"], ["count", "5"], ["legs", "4"]], [["animal", "cats"], ["age", "6"], ["count", "4"], ["legs", "4"]], [["animal", "birds"], ["age", "2"], ["count", "1"], ["legs", "2"]]]
```

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the tip